# How to add words from a single item in a list

Tags: python, list, join

I am trying to join words from a list and convert it to a string

I've tried .join method, but since I only have one item in my list it does not work.

My input = 
`list = ['Vehicles, Parts & Accessories,Automotive Body Paint']`

Desired output = `str = Vehicles-Parts-&-Accessories-Automotive-Body-Paint`

Comment: I'm not sure that you've provided valid input and output. Please, doublecheck your question and let us know is provided data correct. Also, add what have you tried so far, share your code.

Comment: Your example has a single item string in a list, so the task would be to convert the string you have to the one you want. Would a more accurate question be "How to separate words in a string then join by a character?"

Comment: Also, what do you want to do with commas? Just ignore them?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python split string into words" and "Python join words", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Comment: Asked and answered many times

Answer (score 1):

First, your list is only one item, so access it by `my_str = my_lst[0]`. Then remove the `,` and replace  by `-`:

```
my_str = my_str.replace(',','').replace(' ', '-')
```

Output:

```
'Vehicles-Parts-&-AccessoriesAutomotive-Body-Paint'
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're looking for:

```
lst = ['Vehicles, Parts & Accessories,Automotive Body Paint']
string = lst[0].replace(',',' ').replace(' ','-')
```

Output:

```
'Vehicles--Parts-&-Accessories-Automotive-Body-Paint'
```

Note: try not to use `str` or `list` as variable names, because Python reserves those for inner use and you'll disable them that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do this, let's find all groups of repeated word characters or `&` and join them with `-`. Solution works on a list of multiple strings.

```py
import re

l = ['Vehicles, Parts & Accessories,Automotive Body Paint']
['-'.join(re.findall('[\w&]+', words)) for words in l]
```

Output

```py
['Vehicles-Parts-&-Accessories-Automotive-Body-Paint']
```